# Difference between WebApi controllers and WCF WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between WCF Web API and ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451298/whats-the-difference-between-wcf-web-api-and-asp-net-web-api)

I've started looking at the new features of MVC 4. One of the notable new features is ApiControllers.

I still cannot understand why to use this rather than WCF WebAPI? Is that because Microsoft's trying to fadeout WCF WebAPI, or gather all tool sets in a single place which is an MVC 4 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Migrate%20from%20WCF%20Web%20API%20to%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API).